# efficient estimation of a model with heteroskedastic errors

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

What is the nature of the question below? My sense is that this is a model with heteroskedastic errors and so would require FGLS estimation. Am I on the right track in terms of solving the question of how to efficiently estimate the model?

Consider the model

$$y_i = X_i\beta + \epsilon $$

for i = 1,2...

where $y_t$ is a (T x 1) dependent variable and X is a (T x k) matrix of explanatory varibales.
$\beta$ is a (k x 1) vector of coefficients $\alpha$ is a constant and $\epsilon$ is a (T x 1) error term.

Assume:
$E[\epsilon_i | X] = 0$ 
; $E[\epsilon_i^2|X] = \sigma_i^2 I_T$ for i=1,2...,n 
and assume that
$E[\epsilon_i,\epsilon_j'] = \sigma_{ij} I_T$ for $i$ not equal to $j$

How would one efficiently estimate this model?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have heterokedastic errors, you should account for that in your estimation of the variance. One consistent estimator for the variance matrix would be the White (1980) estimator, given by:
$$ \Psi = (X'X)^{-1} X' \hat \Omega X (X'X)^{-1} $$

Where $\hat \Omega = diag(\hat u_1^{2},...\hat u_n^{2})$, which is a diagonal matrix of the squared residuals of OLS estimates.